# VBA - using for loop in named range to add dd/mm/yyyy to increasing hh/mm cells values

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am very new to `VBA` so please forgive the question, I am working on writing a code that will loop through a named range and add the `dd/mm/yyyy`, with the dd increasing incrementally when the cell value passes `0000`.
I am struggling with the action after the `if time1 < time2 then statement`.
Specifically how to reference the `'dd/mm/yyyy'` in the `active cell` but not the `hh/mm`.

Any suggestions or views on a better logic of how to do this!

```
Sub changeDate()

Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("starttime")
Dim cel As Range
Dim time2 As String
Dim time1 As String

Sheets("Sheet3").Range("starttime").Activate

For Each cel In rng.Cells
    cel.Select
    time1 = ActiveCell.Value
    time2 = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value
         If time1 < time2 Then
         '****  use time1 dd/mm/yyyy + time2 hh/mm for value of time2
         End If
         If time1 > time2 Then
         '**** use (time1 dd/mm/yyyy + one day) + time2 hh/mm for value of time2
         End If
Next cel

End Sub

' example of named range starttime 
'02/01/2018 07:25
'00/01/1900 12:28
'00/01/1900 17:38
'00/01/1900 01:01
'00/01/1900 08:07
'00/01/1900 13:22
'00/01/1900 18:33
'00/01/1900 01:45
'00/01/1900 08:47
'00/01/1900 14:20
```

Comment: `time2 - Fix(time2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FIX() to get the integer part of any number, in this case the date part of the date-time value.  Also, you should avoid celecting cells, it slows down execution of the code, you don't even have to assing temporary variables to the values you are comparing:

```
For Each cel In Rng.Cells
    With cel
         If .Value < .Offset(1, 0).Value Then
         '****  use time1 dd/mm/yyyy + time2 hh/mm for value of time2
         ElseIf .Value > Fix(.Offset(1, 0).Value) Then
         '**** use (time1 dd/mm/yyyy + one day) + time2 hh/mm for value of time2
         End If
    End With
Next cel
```

Cheers,
Michal

Answer (score 0):

This Solved my issue

```
Sub datechange()
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("starttime")
Dim cel As Range
Dim day1 As Date
day1 = ("01/01/2018")

For Each cel In rng.Cells
With cel

     If .Value > .Offset(1, 0).Value Then
            cel = .Value + day1
            day1 = day1 + 1
     ElseIf .Value < (.Offset(1, 0).Value) Then
            cel = .Value + day1

     End If
End With
```

Next cel

End Sub